# Functions intervals

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have 3 functions, how can I plot them using differents intervals ?

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(-5,5,100)
y = 2*x+1
k = 3*x+2
i = 2*x+2
plt.plot(x, y, '-r', label='y=2x+1')
plt.plot(x, k, '-r', label='k =3x+2')
plt.plot(x, i, '-r', label='i =2x+2')
plt.title('3 functions on 3 intervals')
plt.xlabel('x', color='#1C2833')
plt.ylabel('y', color='#1C2833')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

Wanted style : 3 intervals, 3 linear functions :

[image]

This is what I get :
[image]

My wish is to draw the first function 2*x+1 on the following interval [x:2->x:8].

The second function 3*x+2 has to be plotted on the interval [x:8->x:12]

The third function 2*x+2 has to be plotted on the interval [x:12->x:20]

Is it possible ?

Edit :
Ended up with this :

```
x = np.linspace(-5,0,100)
t = np.linspace(0,5,100)
m = np.linspace(5,10,100)
y = 2*x+1
k = 3*x-2
i = 2*x+2
plt.plot(x, y, '-r', label='y=2x+1')
plt.plot(t, k, '-r', label='k =3x-2')
plt.plot(m, i, '-r', label='i =2x+2')
```

Result :

[image]

Comment: Why are you using the same `x` for every function?

Comment: Because I need to display three functions on the same grid.

Comment: Then you're passing the exact same interval to every function. "I need to display three functions on the same grid" doesn't require the same x-values for each function.

Comment: Ok, but how should I specify intervals ?

Comment: Using `linspace` multiple times, or indexing on the current `x`.

Comment: When you calculate `y`, k`, and `i`, you should use `x`, `t`, and `m` respectively.

Comment: Also, the arguments you pass to `linspace` should obviously be the intervals that you want. According to your post, that is `(2,8)`, (8,12), and (12,20).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it this that you want?

[image]

```
In [33]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    ...: import numpy as np
    ...: 
    ...: xs = [np.linspace(0,4), np.linspace(-3, 5), np.linspace(4, 10)]
    ...: fs = [np.cos, np.sin, lambda x:np.sin(x)-2*np.cos(x)]
    ...: for x, f in zip(xs, fs):
    ...:     plt.plot(x, f(x), label=f.__name__)
    ...: plt.legend()
    ...: plt.show()
```

Plotting a linear function is no different,

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

xs = [np.linspace(0,4), np.linspace(-3, 5), np.linspace(4, 10)]
fs = [np.cos, np.sin, lambda x:(x-6)*0.5]
fs[-1].__name__ = 'x/2-3'
for x, f in zip(xs, fs):
    plt.plot(x, f(x), label=f.__name__)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

If and only if you are going to plot ONLY LINEAR FUNCTIONS,
another approach could be

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# plotting y = a x + b
y = lambda xmin, xmax, a, b: (a*xmin+b, a*xmax+b)
format = lambda b: ("y = %.2f x + %.2f"if b>=0 else"y = %.2f x – %.2f")
Xmin = [0, 4, 7]
Xmax = [5, 6, 9]
A = [1, 0.5, 3]
B = [-2, 0, 3]

for xmin, xmax, a, b in zip(Xmin, Xmax, A, B):
    plt.plot((xmin, xmax), y(xmin, xmax, a, b),
             label=format(b)%(a, abs(b)))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, kind of, but It should be linear functions... Ok, the command is "linspace" ... thanks

Comment: Linspace doesn't seem to work using multiples linear functions ? I have tried out to replace np.cos by 2*x+1 in your great code with no luck